# Initialization of constructor through constructor produces unexpected result?

Tags: java, initialization

I was confusing since from last several days that how initialization of instance properties through constructor is being done.

Just consider this case

```
class Demo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    Demo(int a,int b)
    {
        this.a*=a;//this produces 0 here 
        this.b*=b;//this produces 0 here
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Demo d1=new Demo(20,30);
        d1.show();
    }
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println(this.a);
        System.out.println(this.b);
    }
}
```

How this is initializing here. As i know constructor initialize a value once.assignments can be possible several times.

Comment: Can you post, What are u getting and what are u expecting??

Comment: Since you didn't assign any value to your instance fields, they have a default value; and for `int`s the default value is 0. Hence the result.

Comment: `this.a` = 0 by default, and multiplying it with something doesn't matter as it will still be 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial value for an integer is 0. Your actual assignment is this:

```
a = 0 * 20
```

which will always return 0.

[Some documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the initial value implementation-dependent? A release build leaves it uninitialized, sometimes.

Comment: @user3435400 No, that should never happen.

Comment: No, see the default values section under http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @user3435400: you're thinking about a [*local variable*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), not an *instance variable*. `Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.`

Comment: i mean to say here dear @Jeroen Vannevel that Constructor initializes the default values but i am not using any default constructor rather i force the initialization by a parameterised constructor how it initialized it first 0 then trying with my value here

Answer (score 2):

Integral fields are initialized to 0 by default (as per [JLS §4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)), so multiplying `this.a` (0) and `this.b` (0) by `a` and `b` respectively will not change their value of 0. Zero times any number is still zero.

Answer (score 0):

Initially `this.a` (the class variable) is zero so it will produce zero when you multiply it by `a` (the argument). This is your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Because the default value of int is 0.

So the line

```
this.a*=a;
```

is equivalent to

```
0 * 20
```

which equals 0.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

The initial value for an integer is 0. Your actual assignment is this:

a = 0 * 20

which will always return 0.

It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style.